# Is the language L = {(a,b)* | #a * #b is an odd number} regular?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

Is the following language regular? $$\{ w \in \{a, b\}^* |\ \text{the product of the number of $a$'s and the number of $b$'s is an odd number}\} $$

If i'm not mistaken the condition is the same as having an odd number of $a$'s and an odd number of $b$'s. I have tried using the Pumping Lemma without success. So I'm suspecting it's regular. But I can't think of a regular expression or an automaton that accepts it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is.

Since only the product of two odd numbers is an odd number, you can construct a DFA that only accepts when #$a$ and #$b$ are (both) odd.

The followings states would be:

- $Q_1$ : #$a$ even, #$b$ even
- $Q_2$ : #$a$ even, #$b$ odd
- $Q_3$ : #$a$ odd, #$b$ even
- $Q_4$ : #$a$ odd, #$b$ odd (an accepting state)

The transitions are fairly simply, and I'll leave them to you.

Answer (score 3):

To find the equivalent regular expression, try this approach.

If $\#a$ and $\#b$ are both odd then the total length of the string is even. Divide the string into two character blocks. Each block is either $aa$, $bb$, $ab$ or $ba$.

$aa$ and $bb$ have no effect of the parity of $\#a$ and $\#b$ so they are equivalent as far as our regular expression is concerned. Similarly $ab$ and $ba$ both change the parity of $\#a$ and the parity of $\#b$ so they are also equivalent.

So our regular expression will consist of blocks like $(aa+bb)$ and $(ab+ba)$.

We don't care how many $(aa+bb)$ blocks we see, but we need to see at least one $(ab+ba)$ block, so our regular expression will start with

$(aa+bb)^*(ab+ba) \dots$

After this we need to see an even number of $(ab+ba)$ blocks (remember zero is an even number), possibly interspersed with zero or more $(aa+bb)$ blocks. I'll let you take it from there.